How can I resolve a TypeError reading 'app' error when using Storybook, Vue, Vite, and Pinia?
I have a simple reproduction case at https://github.com/eric-g-97477-vue/dev-tools-plugin-test
To create this, I did the following...
(1) I created the default vue Project
$ npm create vue@latest                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     10:25:02

> npx
> create-vue


Vue.js - The Progressive JavaScript Framework

✔ Project name: … devtools_test
✔ Add TypeScript? … No / Yes
✔ Add JSX Support? … No / Yes
✔ Add Vue Router for Single Page Application development? … No / Yes
✔ Add Pinia for state management? … No / Yes
✔ Add Vitest for Unit Testing? … No / Yes
✔ Add an End-to-End Testing Solution? › No
✔ Add ESLint for code quality? › No

Scaffolding project in /Users/eric.g/depot/vue/devtools_test...

Done. Now run:

  cd devtools_test
  npm install
  npm run dev

I answered "yes" to TypeScript, Vue Router, and Pinia.
(2) I initialized the project with npm install.
(3) I ran npx storybook@latest init
(4) I then setup storybook to be able to use Pinia. Based on https://storybook.js.org/docs/get-started/frameworks/vue3-vite, I added
import { setup, type Preview } from '@storybook/vue3';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
 
setup((app) => {
    app.use(createPinia());
});

to .storybook/preview.js.
(5) I then run npm run storybook and the following error appears in the console when I click around using the stories for button, header, or page.
index.js?v=eab36b85:2603 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'app')
    at Object.get (index.js?v=eab36b85:2603:57)
    at index.js?v=eab36b85:4507:13
    at index.mjs?v=eab36b85:48:66
    at index.mjs?v=eab36b85:48:56

Clearly I have not configured something correctly.
What did I miss?

You are not sharing the contents of your main.ts where your error message is perhaps coming from (most dealing with app is happening in that file).
Outside that, my guess is something is failing in your Vite bundling, and the generated index.js file is seemingly missing things. Look at vite.config.ts perhaps

main.ts can be viewed at https://github.com/eric-g-97477-vue/dev-tools-plugin-test/blob/main/src/main.ts. I did not change main.ts from what one gets by default when following the above procedure.

the stacktrace I see for the error when I run the code is a js file from Vue devtools.  I don't think this affects your app.  Probably some incompatability between latest versions of storybook and vue devtools.  It should be safe to ignore.

That seems possible. I have reported the issue to both groups. Perhaps someone will look into it at some point.
